# SQL Business Intelligence tools to build a dashboard system monitoring transaction database?

Tags: sql-server, business-intelligence

We basically have two main tables (group and set) in transaction database. Using a winform system, each data row is recorded into the database. Amount of the transactions would be 5 rows per second.

Now our goal is to build a dashboard system monitoring the transaction database to mainly show how things are currently going. I am not sure if using MS SQL BI tools such as SSAS, SSIS, and SSRS can help in this situation. So I need advices from experts.

Here are what I am worrying about - please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Frequently querying data from transaction database for dashboard would be big burden - Pro-BI
2. Building warehouse for two tables seems like overkill - Anti-BI

Is there any good reason to use or not to use BI tools?

UPDATE: To clarify my question, I just want to know if there is any other way to build dashboard system without data warehouse and without affecting transaction system.

Comment: "Dashboard" is a very general term that usually seems to mean "a simple GUI that displays some useful information about a business process". Whether or not it uses BI tools is basically irrelevant: you should use the simplest tool - whatever it is - to provide the data. I don't think anyone can give a detailed answer without a lot more details, perhaps you can be more specific about what issues you have? And can you just build a simple tool and see how it performs?

Comment: @Pondlife Thanks for your comment. To start answering your questions in reverse order, I think I can try to build a simple tool but it's a known fact that dashboard will affect the transaction system due to frequent queries of large amount of data. That's part of the reason the whole data warehouse "hype" has been building. So I will not put our time for known failure unless proven otherwise. I hope I can give my details if it will help. But I am not sure it will. Unlike what you think, BI tools and dashboard are closely related. Dashboard is one of the main purposes of data warehouse.

Comment: My point was simply that "dashboard" by itself could mean a commercial reporting product from SAP, a single web page written in-house, or anything in between. It seems that you have an existing database that you want to generate frequently-updated reports from, but you're not sure how to do this and whether or not you need a separate reporting database? Do you already know what the reports should include? Have you tested queries on a copy of your production database? What data volume do you have? How often should the dashboard be updated? Etc.

Comment: Are you still working on this? When you say "how things are going" what do you mean? transaction speed? dollar value? activity by customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a project I've had to monitor follow the flow of orders as they progress through the ordering process.  Rather than hit production tables each time data was needed, I created a table to hold the results populated by a trigger on row insert.

Before the table, I would have to do a long query and perform business logic on the results to count up the statuses.  In real time it was slow.  The table, being precomputed, allows the data to be returned in a instant.

Essentially this is what a fact table in warehouse terms is only I didn't use ETL tools populate it.